# E/Surface﹕ getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xab7519c0

Tags: android, logging

I have a problem with my app. No inserts the data in mysql, the app does not have errors and orange single message log is:

```
 E / Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xab7519c0
```

[image]

I hope you can help me.

Thank you

Comment: check this 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/33262012/2420322

Answer (score 45):

This is an opened issue in Android. You can keep track of this issue [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=192357).

EDIT: The issue is fixed in Android 6.0.1

Answer (score 8):

This happens when you try to set value of TextView to an integer.

When you assign a value of String to a TextView this error disappears.

For example

I have create a Text View in xml file.
I am trying to set the value of that particular text field from java code. I am setting the int value to Text View but I am receiving an error getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xab7519c0
but after changing value from int to String and setting TextView from that String error disappears and app is working fine.

Comment: This actually happened to me when I set textview's text a string in Marshmallow. It is an issue of Marshmallow as they mentioned above.

Answer (score 2):

This is an error of the Android OS running marshmallow and nothing to do with your code, see this issue https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=192357

Try creating a new emulator using API 24 or 25

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure that you are referencing the the Resource correctly. An example of an error may come from the following:

Instead of:

```
String emailText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailText);
```

You type:

```
String emailText = (EditText) findViewById(emailText);
```

The VM will refer emailText of the String and not the Resource Int.

Answer (score 1):

Check your unused XML.

I had this problem too when I deleted `.java` but forgot remove `.xml` files.