# How to install android 6.0.1 emulator in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, android-emulator

I facing this issue on my android emulator [E/Surface﹕ getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xab7519c0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33046375/e-surface-getslotfrombufferlocked-unknown-buffer-0xab7519c0)

But I can't find any option how to udate android version to 6.0.1 of emulator in Android Studio 1.5.1

How can I do it?

Comment: Were you able to fix this issue? I am facing the same issue. If you fixed it, can you please add answer?

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution ? I need to test on 6.0.1...

Comment: I've posted an answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/45301264/550471 that's also relevant to your question

Answer (score 1):

If you create a new Virtual Device under: Tools->Android->AVD Manager or Edit an existing device, you can change the System Image, however as of now I do not see an option for 6.0.1 only 6.0 and 7.0. There appears to be nothing in between even under all three tabs ( Recommended, x86 Images, Other Images ). I was looking for the same thing and to no avail. I also use [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/). but that also lacks the 6.0.1 system image.

Answer (score -4):

It's under Tools > Android > AVD Manager > Actions > Edit (Pencil).

Comment: Unfortunately it isn't it doesn't seem to be available by default, and this is the problem.