# No android 6.0.1 in my android studio

Tags: java, android

I have a problem with my app, and every time I run my app in emulator it returns

> 03-21 21:27:45.560 2947-2960/com.example.miaorunkun.sample5 E/Surface:
>   getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xab84fd20

I know the android 6.0.1 can fix this problem but I don't know how to update my emulator system, because there is no android 6.0.1 in my android studio.

Comment: Did you try launching the standalone sdk manager and downloading the system image?

Comment: Emulator is bad idea try genymotion it makes your Life easier

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate of [How to install android 6.0.1 emulator in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36098482/how-to-install-android-6-0-1-emulator-in-android-studio)

It seems that Android Studio does not offer an image of 6.0.1 yet.