# How to update android emulator to 6.0.1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-sdk-tools, android-6.0.1-marshmallow

I am getting error 'E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xab7cffe0'. Upon research, I got understood that it is known issue in android 6.0. How to update android emulator from 6.0 to 6.0.1? In SDK manager I can see Android 7.0 and android 6.0 are installed ,but 6.0.1 is not there.

[image: Android 7.0 and android 6.0 are installed ,but 6.0.1 is not there]

How should I update 6.0 to 6.0.1?

Also in AVD manager I cannot see any system image other that 6.0. I have installed other versions also, then how to select those versions of android for my AVD?
[image]

Also every time I run my app I get error `emulator: WARNING: UpdateCheck: failed to get a URL: 35 (Error)
emulator: WARNING: UpdateCheck: failed to get the latest version, skipping check (current version '24.4.1'`

Comment: Does the error actually cause anything else than a log entry? If not, move on.

Answer (score 3):

There is no Android 6.0.1 emulator image that's provided by Google.

What I did (on Windows 10 - I don't know if this works for Mac):

1. go to https://www.fosshub.com/Remix-OS.html
2. download RemixOS_**Player** (currently it's 744.04 MB | version: 1.0.110)
3. install it and run it

When you deploy your app from Android Studio you'll see the Android version (see pic below)

[image]