# Android Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) onFinish

Tags: android, segmentation-fault, finalizer

I'm having this exception 5 seconds (approx) when I finish my app:

```
04-24 20:05:17.293 ... E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xe89c73f0
04-24 20:05:22.296 ... A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x695fa3bc in tid 31152 (FinalizerDaemon)
```

If I kill it nothing happens, but if I press "back" until it closes and goes to background, a few seconds later or if I open it again it crashes...

I've just noticed this suddenly, I don't know which code is causing it, I've already comment a lot of it. 
I know this information doesn't help much but where can I look into it? The Logcat doesn't help much wither, it only outputs this two lines.

Thanks for your time.

**EDIT:**
This is the output I get when testing with Android 5.1.0:

```
A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x0 in tid 3815 (FinalizerDaemon)
```

No `getSlotFromBufferLocked` that I was getting when testing in Android 6.0. But as I've mentioned in a comment below, I don't think `getSlotFromBufferLocked` is related to this problem.

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33046375/e-surface-getslotfrombufferlocked-unknown-buffer-0xab7519c0

Comment: Those messages are 5 seconds apart, did nothing happen in between?  If you feel that the first message is the cause of the second, then this should be closed as a duplicate of the above linked question which already covers the getSlotFromBufferLocked issue.

Comment: @ChrisStratton nothing happen but I've notice the first message appears always when the app goes to background, I don't think its related to the problem. Going to check that link. I've updated my question, thanks.

Comment: In that case, you have not posted enough of the error log to receive any meaningful assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved. I have an Object that was supposed to have some of his fields declared as transient. Some of these fields were `Paint` and that was causing that `SIGSEVG` when I was trying to `serialize`/`deserialize` that Object. Kind of strange this error happening only onFinish() because during the app run it could manage those serialization operations...
Oh well, problem fixed, thanks for your time.