# Is this a bug E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xa2ae2310?

Tags: android, android-studio

**this is a part from the code :**

```
 EditText user,password;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
             user = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.user);
             password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pass);
            Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);


        }

            public void login(View v){
                if(JavaLike.getString(user).equals("admin")&&JavaLike.getString(password).equals("admin")){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"OK"+JavaLike.getString(user),Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"not OK"+JavaLike.getString(user),Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                }
            }

        }
```

> 

- 08-27 20:21:51.239 2876-2902/com.example.pc.myapplication E/Surface:

  > getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xaa972750 08-27 20:24:40.280
  >   9008-9055/com.example.pc.myapplication E/Surface:
  >   getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xaa96fd50 08-27 20:24:42.198
  >   9008-9055/com.example.pc.myapplication E/Surface:
  >   getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xaa970a00 08-27 20:26:32.703
  >   9008-9055/com.example.pc.myapplication E/Surface:
  >   getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xaa96fd50 08-27 20:26:34.670
  >   9008-9055/com.example.pc.myapplication E/Surface:
  >   getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xaa96fd50

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was a bug and has been fixed in android 6.0.1 ,here is a link with more infomation
[E/Surface﹕ getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xab7519c0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33046375/e-surface-getslotfrombufferlocked-unknown-buffer-0xab7519c0])

Answer (score 1):

Add `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"`  line to application tag in manifest .