# Android 2d game development

Tags: java, android, 2d-games

I am making a simple game loop and background image moving  but I am getting black screen. Is it problem with my emulator?

**Game.Java**

```
public class Game extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        //removing title
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        //setting contentview and passing this layout to it
        setContentView(new GamePanel(this));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_game, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**Game panel.java**

```
public class GamePanel extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback
{
    public static final int WIDTH = 856;
    public static final int HEIGHT = 480;
    private MainThread thread;
    private Background bg;

    public GamePanel(Context context)
    {
        super(context);

        //add the callback to the surfaceholder to intercept events
        getHolder().addCallback(this);

        thread = new MainThread(getHolder(), this);

        //make gamePanel focusable so it can handle events
        setFocusable(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height){}

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder){
        boolean retry = true;
        while(retry)
        {
            try{thread.setRunning(false);
                thread.join();

            }catch(InterruptedException e){e.printStackTrace();}
            retry = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder){
        bg = new Background(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.grassbg1));
        bg.setvector(-5);
        //we can safely start the game loop
        thread.setRunning(true);
        thread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
    {
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    public void update()
    {
        bg.update();
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        final float scaleFactorX = getWidth()/WIDTH;
        final float scaleFactorY = getHeight()/HEIGHT;
        if (canvas!=null) {
            final int savedState = canvas.save();
            canvas.scale(scaleFactorX, scaleFactorY);
            bg.draw(canvas);
            canvas.restoreToCount(savedState);
        }
        super.draw(canvas);
    }
}
```

**Background.java**

```
public class Background {

    private Bitmap image;
    private int x,y,dx ;

    public Background(Bitmap res)
    {
        image=res;
    }
    public  void update()
    {
        x+=dx;
        if(x<0)
        {
            x=0;
        }
    }
    public void draw( Canvas canvas)
    {
        canvas.drawBitmap(image,x,y,null);
        if(x<0)
        {
            canvas.drawBitmap(image,x+GamePanel.WIDTH,y,null);
        }
    }
    public  void setvector(int dx)
    {
        this.dx=dx;
    }
}
```

**MainThread.java**

```
public class MainThread extends Thread
{
    private int FPS = 30;
    private double averageFPS;
    private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    private GamePanel gamePanel;
    private boolean running;
    public static Canvas canvas;

    public MainThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, GamePanel gamePanel)
    {
        super();
        this.surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
        this.gamePanel = gamePanel;
    }
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        long startTime;
        long timeMillis;
        long waitTime;
        long totalTime = 0;
        int frameCount =0;
        long targetTime = 1000/FPS;

        while(running) {
            startTime = System.nanoTime();
            canvas = null;

            //try locking the canvas for pixel editing
            try {
                canvas = this.surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
                synchronized (surfaceHolder) {
                    this.gamePanel.update();
                    this.gamePanel.draw(canvas);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            finally{
                if(canvas!=null)
                {
                    try {
                        surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                    }
                    catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
                }
            }

            timeMillis = (System.nanoTime() - startTime) / 1000000;
            waitTime = targetTime-timeMillis;

            try{
                this.sleep(waitTime);
            } catch(Exception e){}

            totalTime += System.nanoTime()-startTime;
            frameCount++;
            if(frameCount == FPS)
            {
                averageFPS = 1000/((totalTime/frameCount)/1000000);
                frameCount =0;
                totalTime = 0;
                System.out.println(averageFPS);
            }
        }
    }
    public void setRunning(boolean b)
    {
        running=b;
    }
}
```

**BackGround.java**

```
public class Background {

    private Bitmap image;
    private int x,y,dx;

    public Background(Bitmap res)
    {
        image=res;
    }

    public void update()
    {
        x+=dx;
        if (x<0)
        {
            x=0;
        }
    }

    public void draw( Canvas canvas)
    {
        canvas.drawBitmap(image,x,y,null);
        if (x<0)
        {
            canvas.drawBitmap(image,x+GamePanel.WIDTH,y,null);
        }
    }

    public void setvector(int dx)
    {
        this.dx=dx;
    }
}
```

Output :

```
fahadpirzada.myfirstgame E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xac1790d0
11-07 00:36:20.540 15272-15279/com.example.fahadpirzada.myfirstgame W/art: Suspending all threads took: 87.622ms
11-07 00:37:11.150 15272-15279/com.example.fahadpirzada.myfirstgame W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.025ms
11-07 00:43:29.528 15272-15279/com.example.fahadpirzada.myfirstgame W/art: Suspending all threads took: 17.819ms
11-07 00:43:47.556 15272-15279/com.example.fahadpirzada.myfirstgame W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.342ms
11-07 00:45:31.867 15272-15279/com.example.fahadpirzada.myfirstgame W/art: Suspending all threads took: 25.416ms
11-07 00:45:48.921 15272-15279/com.example.fahadpirzada.myfirstgame W/art: Suspending all threads took: 25.667ms
11-07 00:46:42.139 15272-15279/com.example.fahadpirzada.myfirstgame W/art: Suspending all threads took: 63.547ms
11-07 00:46:54.088 15272-15283/com.example.fahadpirzada.myfirstgame I/art: CollectorTransition marksweep + semispace GC freed 5743(159KB) AllocSpace objects, 1(1608KB) LOS objects, 45% free, 611KB/1123KB, paused 46.409ms total 46.409ms
11-07 00:46:54.548 15272-15286/com.example.fahadpirzada.myfirstgame W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
11-07 00:46:54.548 15272-15286/com.example.fahadpirzada.myfirstgame W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xad9f54c0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
11-07 00:46:54.983 15272-15283/com.example.fahadpirzada.myfirstgame I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 99(9KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 2MB/2MB, paused 3.380ms total 237.021ms
11-07 00:46:55.123 15272-15272/com.example.fahadpirzada.myfirstgame I/Choreographer: Skipped 55 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-07 00:46:57.236 15272-12238/com.example.fahadpirzada.myfirstgame I/System.out: 14.0
```

Comment: did u try to reduce the size of resource?

Comment: This is an opened issue in Android? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33046375/e-surface-getslotfrombufferlocked-unknown-buffer-0xab7519c0]