# How to control activity by voice?

Tags: android, speech-recognition

I have an application that receives messages and reads them. I want to control reading, I mean when I say Read it Read the message If you say do not read it comes out of the application (see a lot of codes but did not understand well) Please help.

Comment: This is called "speech recognition", you can ask google for further details.

Comment: thank you sir, but I want ask speech recognition doing the arabic language?

Comment: Yes, different flavors of Arabic are supported.

Comment: I have do code for speech recognition but I have error Can help me to solve this error ?

Comment: this is error(E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xb4097470
)

Comment: This error is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33046375/e-surface-getslotfrombufferlocked-unknown-buffer-0xab7519c0, you are trying to assign value of textview from integer

Comment: Text1= ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.text1));startActivityForResult(intent1, RESULT_SPEECH);
                Text1.setText("");                                                                                    (where is error and I have change)and this part of code

Comment: You need to edit the question and provide complete code you use and details about error you get.