# Unable to retrieve same pending intent.

Tags: android, android-intent, alarmmanager, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

I am unable to retrieve the same intent even after passing the same ID of the intent.

I have checked the broadcast receiver has the exact same context used while creating the pending intent.

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

public static String NOTIFICATION_ID = "notification-id";
public static String NOTIFICATION = "notification";
public static MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
public static NotificationManager notificationManager;
public static Notification notification;
public static int id;
Context ctx;

@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
    ctx = context;

    Log.d("WTF", ""+intent.getAction());

    if (intent.getAction() != null) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        switch (action) {
            case "SNOOZE":
                Log.v("shuffTest", "Pressed Snoozed");
                break;
            case "STOP_ACTION":
                Log.v("shuffTest", "Pressed Stop");
                mMediaPlayer.stop();
                notificationManager.cancel(id);
                stopReceiverServices();
                break;
        }
    } else {
        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = intent.getParcelableExtra(NOTIFICATION);
        id = intent.getIntExtra(NOTIFICATION_ID, 0);
        notificationManager.notify(id, notification);
        playAlarmSound();
    }

    // This is the Intent to deliver to our service.
    //Intent service = new Intent(context, SimpleWakefulService.class);
    // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
    //startWakefulService(context, service)
}

public void stopReceiverServices(){
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(ctx.getApplicationContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
    notificationIntent.putExtra(AlarmReceiver.NOTIFICATION_ID, 123);
    notificationIntent.putExtra(AlarmReceiver.NOTIFICATION, notification);
    Log.d("TAG", "Context A1: "+ctx.getApplicationContext().toString());
    Log.d("TAG", "Context A2: "+ctx.toString());
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) ctx.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Log.d("TAG", "AlarmManager Before: " + alarmManager);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctx.getApplicationContext(), 987654321, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    Log.d("TAG", "PendingIntent Before: " + pendingIntent);
    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
    pendingIntent.cancel();
    Log.d("TAG", "AlarmManager After: " + alarmManager);
    Log.d("TAG", "PendingIntent After: " + pendingIntent);
}
/..
}
```

While Creating the PendingIntent.

```
void setAlarm(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
    notificationIntent.putExtra(AlarmReceiver.NOTIFICATION_ID, 123);
    notificationIntent.putExtra(AlarmReceiver.NOTIFICATION, getNotification("Wake Up! Wake Up"));

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context.getApplicationContext(), 987654321, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minuteOfHour);

    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

    Log.d("TAG", "AlarmManager After setting : " + alarmManager);
    Log.d("TAG", "PendingIntent After setting : " + pendingIntent);

    Log.d("Ctx setAlarm1 ", context.getApplicationContext().toString());
}
```

Logcat :

```
06-14 20:01:39.297 23767-23767/com.apps.testapp D/TAG: AlarmManager After setting : android.app.AlarmManager@ed1e807
06-14 20:01:39.297 23767-23767/com.apps.testapp D/TAG: PendingIntent After setting : PendingIntent{7c1d34: android.os.BinderProxy@ff6775d}
06-14 20:01:39.297 23767-23767/com.apps.testapp D/Ctx setAlarm1: com.apps.testapp.ApplicationMain@33d58d2
06-14 20:01:39.305 23767-23881/com.apps.testapp E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xb91721a8
06-14 20:01:44.334 23767-23767/com.apps.testapp D/WTF: null
06-14 20:01:44.545 23767-23767/com.apps.testapp D/MediaPlayer: setSubtitleAnchor in MediaPlayer
06-14 20:01:49.772 23767-23767/com.apps.testapp D/WTF: STOP_ACTION
06-14 20:01:49.773 23767-23767/com.apps.testapp V/shuffTest: Pressed Stop
06-14 20:01:49.777 23767-23767/com.apps.testapp D/TAG: Context A1: com.apps.testapp.ApplicationMain@33d58d2
06-14 20:01:49.777 23767-23767/com.apps.testapp D/TAG: Context A2: android.app.ReceiverRestrictedContext@3af302a
06-14 20:01:49.777 23767-23767/com.apps.testapp D/TAG: AlarmManager Before: android.app.AlarmManager@ed1e807 
06-14 20:01:49.780 23767-23767/com.apps.testapp D/TAG: PendingIntent Before: PendingIntent{cc07e1b: android.os.BinderProxy@8441bb8}
06-14 20:01:49.782 23767-23767/com.apps.testapp D/TAG: AlarmManager After: android.app.AlarmManager@ed1e807
06-14 20:01:49.782 23767-23767/com.apps.testapp D/TAG: PendingIntent After: PendingIntent{cc07e1b: android.os.BinderProxy@8441bb8}
```

Comment: what are you trying to do? what do you mean by "exactly same intent" ?

Comment: I wanna cancel the pendingIntent when users dismisses the notification.

Comment: Why do you think this isnt' working as you want? What do you expect to see?

Answer (score 1):

In alarmManager and PendingIntent remove getApplicationConext()

```
void setAlarm(Context context) {

...

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context), 987654321, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

...
}
```

Comment: context.getApplicationContext() and context returns the same value, it goes change anything.

Comment: Refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33046375/e-surface-getslotfrombufferlocked-unknown-buffer-0xab7519c0/33898248

Comment: ^ that issue is another story, nothing to do with pendingIntent or alarmManager.