# Getting an error on recreate() inside onOptionsItemSelected() in API 23 / Marshmallow

Tags: android, android-activity, android-6.0-marshmallow, recreate

I am trying to make my App, which works perfectly on API<23 devices, to work on an API 23 device. 
It crash in the following senario.
The user changes settings via `options menu`. If they tap slowly on the menu option (so there is time to see the option being highlighted), everything is fine, but if they tap briefly, the App crashes.
I know it's a quit strange behaviour and I have spend some time trying to understand what fires the error. The error occurs after recreate() which is in `onOptionItemSelected`. I put a timeout before recreate() to test if the option is "validated" but that didn't work. 
I can only think of some kind of bug in API 23 because it worked before with other APIs.
Here is a snippet of my code (cut down to a minimum):

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) { 
   switch (item.getItemId()) {
      case R.id.menu_item_1:
            //... some code goes here
            recreate();
            return true;
            // some other options ..
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
 }
```

After creating a new project with a blank activity and just adding inside onOptionsItemSelected()

```
if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
    recreate();
    return true;
}
```

the app still crashes.

Here is the logcat:

> ```
> 10-20 23:12:10.062 3217-3245/? E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown    buffer: 0xab3d1b80
> 10-20 23:12:11.050 3217-3245/? E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xb4013030
> 10-20 23:12:11.075 3217-3245/? E/Surface: queueBuffer: error queuing buffer to SurfaceTexture, -19
> 10-20 23:12:11.075 3217-3245/? E/EGL_emulation: tid 3245: swapBuffers(324): error 0x3003 (EGL_BAD_ALLOC)
> 10-20 23:12:11.075 3217-3245/? A/OpenGLRenderer: Encountered EGL error 12291 EGL_BAD_ALLOC during rendering
> 10-20 23:12:11.075 3217-3245/? A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 3245 (RenderThread)
> ```

Comment: "I have an error message" -- please post the Java stack trace or other error message.

Comment: I still don't what is problem by seeing logs but  recraete() can be replaced with invalidateOptionsMenu()

Comment: I have already tried invalidateOptionsMenu() but it doesn't do the trick of recreating/refreshing the page. I use it for refreshing menu options and it does work well for that purpose.

Comment: Here are [potential solutions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33146256/4244416) from another related post on SO. It might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was indeed a bug. After I reported, it has been since fixed by Google.
It can be followed here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=195966

Meantime my workaround is to replace `recreate()` by:

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    finish();
    startActivity(intent);
```

But the reload is not as smooth as with recreate() (I can see a little flashing).