# android First app

Tags: android, android-studio, android-6.0-marshmallow, nexus-5

I am new to android. I try to learn android and following this tutorial

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html

which asks to change the default new project on android studio to the 
following 
for **content.xml** to

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >
<EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/edit_message" />
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_send" />
```

and the **strings.xml** to

```
 <string name="app_name">My First App</string>
<string name="edit_message">Enter a message</string>
<string name="button_send">Send</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="title_activity_main">MainActivity</string>
```

I am running my app on nexus 5 with marshmallow and getting this error

> 27032-27063/com.example.free.test E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked:
>   unknown buffer: 0xaeef3760

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32561479/android-studio-getslotfrombufferlocked-unknown-buffer-error

Comment: i did a comparision with the defalut code that worked first time , and just adding app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" to to linearlayout makes it work , why ?

Comment: That error will really help us a lot to understand the problem as it contains every information needed.

Comment: think so you put your layout inside the coordinator layout so that adding app:layout_behaviour makes it work.