# Android getSlotFromBufferLocked

Tags: java, android

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_register, container, false);
    Button btnRegister = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.actionregister);
    final EditText nameText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.rusername);
    final EditText passText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.rpassword);
    final EditText passConText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.rpasswordr);

    btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            validate(nameText,passText,passConText);
        }

    });
    return view;
}

    public void validate(EditText nameText, EditText passText, EditText passConText){

    String userName = nameText.getText().toString();
    String password = passText.getText().toString();
    String passCon = passConText.getText().toString();

    if(userName.trim().length() == 0)
    {
        nameText.setError("Gebruikersnaam moet ingevuld worden");
        if (password != passCon){
            passConText.setError("Wachtwoorden moeten gelijk en ingevuld zijn");
        }
    }
    else{
        if (password != passCon){
            passConText.setError("Wachtwoorden moeten gelijk en ingevuld zijn");
        }
        else{
            mListener.register(userName, password);
        }
    }
}



@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof RegisterListener) {
        mListener = (RegisterListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement NextPage");
    }
}



public interface RegisterListener {
    public void register(String userName,String password);
}
```

So after adding the validation code, I keep getting an getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer error. My app is still working, but I don't understand why I keep getting errors. Does anyone know why this is happening and what I should change? When trying to run the app it doesn't go to the start page anymore either...

Error report:

```
07-25 18:06:10.853 2452-2598/com.example.hoofdgebruiker.winkelskortrijk E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xaa04afb0
07-25 18:06:10.885 2452-2598/com.example.hoofdgebruiker.winkelskortrijk E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xaa04ae60

                                                                                   --------- beginning of system
07-25 18:06:12.852 2452-2598/com.example.hoofdgebruiker.winkelskortrijk E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xaa0485b0
```

I don't understand the answer to the other question. I still have no clue how to solve this, so please someone explain to me what is wrong in my code. I had looked at the other question before even posting here...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android studio getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32561479/android-studio-getslotfrombufferlocked-unknown-buffer-error)

Comment: @basic But I don't get the answers there... Please explain