# How to validate register page android

Tags: android, validation, android-fragments

Edit: for instance, if I just do this:

```
            boolean thiscreateserror = false;
            if (thiscreateserror == true) {
                mListener.register(userName, password);
            }
            else{}

07-25 20:24:25.552 2385-2529/com.example.hoofdgebruiker.winkelskortrijk W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/data/com.example.hoofdgebruiker.winkelskortrijk/lib
07-25 20:24:25.574 2385-2555/com.example.hoofdgebruiker.winkelskortrijk E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xb4017ef0
07-25 20:24:27.559 2385-2555/com.example.hoofdgebruiker.winkelskortrijk E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xaa1e6d10
```

Edit2: I'm very sorry. I actually seem to be getting this error every time I try to relaunch the app after registering. Maybe the problem lies somewhere else?

My database:

```
public class MyDBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "winkelskortrijk.db";
private static final String TABLE_USERS = "users";
private static final String TABLE_FAVOURITES = "favorieten";

public static final String COLUMN_ID = "id";
public static final String COLUMN_USERNAME = "username";
public static final String COLUMN_PASSWORD = "password";

public static final String COLUMN_ID2 = "id2";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "naam";
public static final String COLUMN_STRAAT = "straat";
public static final String COLUMN_HUISNR = "nr";
public static final String COLUMN_POSTCODE = "postcode";
public static final String COLUMN_DEELGEMEENTE = "deelgemeente";
public static final String COLUMN_GEMEENTE = "gemeente";
public static final String COLUMN_ADRES = "adres";

public MyDBHandler(Context context, String name,
                   SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    String CREATE_USERS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " +
            TABLE_USERS + "("
            + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            + COLUMN_USERNAME + " TEXT,"
            + COLUMN_PASSWORD + " TEXT"
            + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_USERS_TABLE);

    String CREATE_FAVOURITES_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " +
            TABLE_FAVOURITES + "("
            + COLUMN_ID2 + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
            + COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + COLUMN_STRAAT + " TEXT,"
            + COLUMN_HUISNR + " INTEGER,"
            + COLUMN_POSTCODE + " INTEGER,"
            + COLUMN_DEELGEMEENTE + " TEXT,"
            + COLUMN_GEMEENTE + " TEXT,"
            + COLUMN_ADRES + " TEXT,"
            + COLUMN_ID + " INT, "
            + "FOREIGN KEY(" + COLUMN_ID + ") REFERENCES "
            + TABLE_USERS + "(id) " + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_FAVOURITES_TABLE);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion,
                      int newVersion) {

}


public User findUser(User user) {

    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_USERS + " WHERE "
            + COLUMN_USERNAME + " = '" + user.getUserName()+"'";

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    User findUser = new User();

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        findUser.setUserName(cursor.getString(1));
        findUser.setPassword(cursor.getString(2));
        cursor.close();
    } else {
        findUser = null;
    }
    db.close();
    return findUser;

}

public void addOrUpdateUser(User user){

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_USERNAME, user.getUserName());
    values.put(COLUMN_PASSWORD, user.getPassword());
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    db.insert(TABLE_USERS, null, values);
    db.close();
}
```

My main activity:

```
@Override
public void register(String userName, String password){
    User userNew = new User();
    User user = new User();
    userNew.setUserName(userName);
    userNew.setPassword(password);
    MyDBHandler dbHandler = new MyDBHandler(this,null,null,1);
    user = dbHandler.findUser(userNew);
    if (user == null){
        dbHandler.addOrUpdateUser(userNew);
        navigateToLogin();
    }
    else{
        navigateToRegister();
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to something like this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_register, container, false);
    Button btnRegister = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.actionregister);
    final EditText nameText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.rusername);
    final EditText passText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.rpassword);
    final EditText passConText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.rpasswordr);

    btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(validate(nameText, passText, passConText))
                mListener.register(userName, password);
        }

    });
    return view;
}

private boolean validate(EditText nameText, EditText passText, EditText passConText) {


        String userName = nameText.getText().toString();
        String password = passText.getText().toString();
        String passCon = passConText.getText().toString();
     boolean isValidated = true;
    if(userName.trim().length() == 0){
        nameText.setError("Username has to be entered");
        isValidated = false;
    }
    if(password.trim().length() == 0)
    {
        passText.setError("Password has to be entered");
        isValidated = false;
    }
    else {
    if(!pass.equals(passCon)){
            passText.setError("Passwords have to be matching");
            isValidated = false;
    }
return isValidated;

}
```

> Note : Make nameText, passText instance variable so it is accessible
>   inside the function.

Comment: I can't make them variable, then I get an error saying variable nameText is accessed from within inner class, must be declared final... This is also what I tried to do before, but I can't not set mListener.register(userName, password), which is the case here because it only gets set when it meets the conditions, but for some reason it has to be set?

Answer (score 0):

When you write `if(password != passCon)`
you compare the reference and not the string value.
Try to use `if(!passCon.equals(password))` instead.

Comment: That's a good point. However, that's not the real issue I'm dealing with here. I edited my code to explain it better.

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32561479/android-studio-getslotfrombufferlocked-unknown-buffer-error/33262012#33262012

Comment: So this is not an actual problem? There is no actual programming error in my code?