# Unable to transit from material-intro to main activity layout

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, oncreate, setcontentview

I am creating an app that uses material-intro slide for user guide and pops up when the app starts, but i am unable to transit from the Slide to my activity_main layout.Even the screen appears blank when setContentView is used.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    setFullscreen(true);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    addSlide(new SimpleSlide.Builder()
            .title(R.string.title)
            .description(R.string.description)
            .image(R.mipmap.icon)
            .background(R.color.background)
            .backgroundDark(R.color.background_dark)
            .build());

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

[The github link to the dependencies](https://github.com/HeinrichReimer/material-intro)

MainActivity code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

private TaskDbHelper mHelper;
private ListView mTaskListView;
private ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    /*SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

      if(!prefs.getBoolean("new1",false)){

        //Only 1st time run code here

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("new1", true);
        editor.commit();
     }*/

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mHelper = new TaskDbHelper(this);
    mTaskListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_todo);
    updateUI();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_add_task:

        final EditText taskEditText = new EditText(this);
        AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Add new task")
               // .setMessage("What do you want to do next?")
                .setView(taskEditText)
                .setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        String task = String.valueOf(taskEditText.getText());
                        if(task != null && !task.isEmpty()) {
                            SQLiteDatabase db = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                            values.put(TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_TITLE, task);
                            db.insertWithOnConflict(TaskContract.TaskEntry.TABLE,
                                    null,
                                    values,
                                    SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
                            updateUI();
                            db.close();
                        } else {

                        }
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
                .create();
        dialog.show();

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

private void updateUI() {
    ArrayList<String> taskList = new ArrayList<>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = mHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TaskContract.TaskEntry.TABLE,
            new String[]{TaskContract.TaskEntry._ID, TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_TITLE},
            null, null, null, null, null);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_TITLE);
        taskList.add(cursor.getString(idx));
    }

    if (mAdapter == null) {
        mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
                R.layout.item_todo,
                R.id.task_title,
                taskList);
        mTaskListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    } else {
        mAdapter.clear();
        mAdapter.addAll(taskList);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    cursor.close();
    db.close();
}

public void deleteTask(View view) {
    View parent = (View) view.getParent();
    TextView taskTextView = (TextView) parent.findViewById(R.id.task_title);
    String task = String.valueOf(taskTextView.getText());
    SQLiteDatabase db = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TaskContract.TaskEntry.TABLE,
            TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_TITLE + " = ?",
            new String[]{task});
    db.close();
    updateUI();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Because You have to set a button that finish the intro and get you to the main activity.
and you do not need to

```
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

You have to put all this code in separate class other than main activity, otherwise you can not go there.

following is sample code from the library you mention

```
addSlide(new SimpleSlide.Builder()
                    .title(R.string.title_material_bold)
                    .description(R.string.description_material_bold)
                    .image(R.drawable.art_material_bold)
                    .background(R.color.color_material_bold)
                    .backgroundDark(R.color.color_dark_material_bold)
                    .scrollable(scrollable)
                    .buttonCtaLabel("finish")
                    .buttonCtaClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) 
                        {
                            Intent main=new Intent(MainIntro.this,MainActivity.class);
                            startActivity(main);
                        }
                    })
                    .build());
```

for more info refer this class

[MainIntroActivity.java](https://github.com/HeinrichReimer/material-intro/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/heinrichreimersoftware/materialintro/demo/MainIntroActivity.java)

Comment: Used it.Unable to switch from activity MainIntroActivity to MainActivity, app crashes

Comment: `<activity android:name=".MainIntroActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">`  the Appmanifest code

Comment: could u post your log cat?

Comment: [Link to log cat file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8WPEL3mtMEGYjI0ODdSOFN2a0E/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: i mean logcat of particular time where your app crashes.

Comment: 07-26 12:20:33.304 13588-13632/com.naive.LISTY E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xa9fb4e00

Comment: it is not the reason i think..it is possibly due to [getSlotFromBufferLocked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32561479/android-studio-getslotfrombufferlocked-unknown-buffer-error)

Comment: any idea how to fix?.when i directly start the MainActivity their is no problem. the problem is only their when switching.

Comment: i can help if u post log ;)

Comment: In the MainActivity onCreate i use SQLdatabase list update. Can this be any reason ?

Comment: it can be.upvote answer if u find helpful.post the logcat error where it indicate any exception,class name or any activity name

Comment: [Link to full log Cat](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1DJtGqJvkQfLLp5n-PMdwT3wb7MaqiAjzFIRf-gA0AVE/edit?usp=sharing)