# Setting Image to ImageButton randomly on every click

Tags: android, button, random, imagebutton

I am trying to make a button from an image, and the idea is that every click on the button changes the image so the shape and look of the button change too.

> **E.g., every click gives a point, and every shape or
>   "image" is selected based on an algorithm I made for this purpose**

I have these three variables with values generated randomly in this code below:

```
rand = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
x = rand.nextInt(3);
y = rand.nextInt(8);
z = rand.nextInt(10);
```

The generated numbers are assigned to the string to create the next **`id`** of the image with this code:

```
String myID = "R.id.myImage_" + x + y + z;
```

I use this code:

```
int resource = getResources().getIdentifier(myID, "drawable", "com.asgames.package");
```

However, I still get an error that the image is not found.

Comment: All the images have their own IDs, which is their name: `R.drawable.image1`, `R.drawable.image2`, etc. Why do you need them to have random IDs ?

Comment: as I said I am new to Android,Sorry...[Updated the question] I have my random selected ID how to set the Image Button exactly as the randomly generated ID? @JonZarate

Comment: What are you trying to do with ImageButton's that have random ID's?

Comment: Each ImageButton also has it's ID. Which is defined in the XML: `android:id="@id+/imageButton1"`, `android:id="@id+/imageButton1"`, etc.

Comment: Let me explain, Let's say  `x=0 y=2 z=3` so that's mean the selected image is **myImage023** how I can set it as Image button? @tash @JonZarate

Comment: "I still get an error" -> *what* error?

Comment: the image is not found but as you can see that someone helped me and the solution worked well for me

Comment: Clarify via edits, not comments. And where is your [mre]? See [ask] & other [help] links.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To generate a random id for a `View` in android, you can use the `generateViewId()` which is a method in the `View` class bundled inside the Android library, the docs says:

> Generate a value suitable for use in setId(int). This value will not
>   collide with ID values generated at build time by aapt for R.id.

check the official documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#generateViewId()).

So now you can do the following:

```
    int imageCoordinates = x + y + z;
    int imageId = View.generateViewId() + imageCoordinates;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by using the following code:

```
int resource = getResources().getIdentifier(myID, "drawable", "com.your.package");
```

PS: Take out the "`R.id.`" from the name.

Comment: It worked weel, but It gives this error **getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer error** @Aftab Hussain

Comment: Apparently, this is an open issue for Marshmellow. Look at 'Itai Hanski''s answer at 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32561479/android-studio-getslotfrombufferlocked-unknown-buffer-error

Answer (score 0):

1. Rename yuor image like image1, image2,..., image150.
2. Generate a random number in between 1 to 150 (both inclusive).
3. Use below code to get image resource id. (Use "mipmap" instead of "drawable" if you have placed the images in mipmap folder)

   ```
   String myID = "image"+ generatedRandomNumber;
   int resource = getResources().getIdentifier(myID, "drawable", "com.your.package");
   ```
4. Use this resource id to set the image for `ImageButton`.